# In $y = 1.5x + 0.9$, is $y$ directly proportional to $x$?

Tags: terminology

If $y$-intercept not equal $0$, is it still considered directly proportional?

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried? Do you understand what is meant by directly proportional?

Comment: @Mathmo123 It's not clear what "what have you tried" means for a *terminology* question.

Comment: @behaviour the terminology tag was added 5 hours ago...asking the op to clarify what isn't understood is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Directly proportional" means exactly that --- if $x$ doubles, then so does $y$. But if the $y$-intercept of the linear equation is nonzero, then the doubling condition does not hold.

Answer (score 1):

No. Direct proportion is $y = c x$.